# Can someone explain what the foldid argument in glmnet does?

Tags: r, lasso, ridge-regression, glmnet

I m trying to determine what **alpha** to use in my `glmnet` function, but the help file tells me:

> Note that cv.glmnet does NOT search for values for alpha. A specific value should be supplied, else alpha=1 is assumed by default. **If users would like to cross-validate alpha as well, they should call cv.glmnet with a pre-computed vector foldid**, and then use this same fold vector in separate calls to cv.glmnet with different values of alpha.

However, I do not understand:

1. What the foldid vector / argument is.
2. How to create the foldid vector
3. How to use foldid argument.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this parameter makes sense when you are comparing different models. so you would like to control the folds and pre-specify them. To select alpha, you have to try different values of the parameter.

Answer (score 6):

`fold.id` allows the user to pre-specify the cross validation folds for `cv.glmnet`.  For example, if I have some data

```
x    | y    | fold.id
-----+------+--------
0    | 1    | 1
1    | 1    | 1
0    | 0    | 2
1    | 2    | 2
.    | .    | .
```

Then passing in the indicated column as the `fold.id` argument to `cv.glmnet` will cause (for example) the first two observations to reside in the same fold, and the third and fourth observations to reside in the same (different) fold.

The authors are suggesting that if you would like to choose between some discrete collection of $\alpha$ based on a cross validation estimate of some error at an optimal $\lambda_{\alpha}$, then it is best practice to use the same fold structure in each of your cross validations when determining each $\lambda_{\alpha}$.

Comment: So the fold.id needs to be a matrix with the same number of rows as my input matrix (x)? Is that right?

Comment: Is there a strategic way to set the fold.id, or is it completely arbitrary? In other words, how do I define a suitable fold.id?

Comment: Just a vector of integers I believe.  But yes, the vector should have one entry for each row of your design matrix.

Comment: That depends on your data, but the simplest case is covered by something like `rbinom(now(X), n.folds, rep(1/n.folds, n.folds))`.

Comment: Whats the best way to set this up for time series data?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Glmnet Vignette](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html), one way to set-up the `foldid` for glmnet is by:

```
foldid<-sample(1:10,size=length(y),replace=TRUE)
```

And then apply to a series of alphas:

```
cv1=cv.glmnet(x,y,foldid=foldid,alpha=1)
cv.5=cv.glmnet(x,y,foldid=foldid,alpha=.5)
cv0=cv.glmnet(x,y,foldid=foldid,alpha=0)
```

The `sample()` function basically allows you to generate a vector of random numbers in the range you supply (= 1:nfolds) for the length of the response variable matrix *y*. In this way, you assign each of your input matrix rows to a random (but now set) fold.

Comment: Anyone understand how the authors of the [vignette](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) decided that alpha=1 is best based on the 4 graphs they print ? Their quote: We see that lasso (alpha=1) does about the best here. We also see that the range of lambdas used differs with alpha." ... I just don't understand how they determined alpha=1 is best??

Comment: I believe the reason is that it uses the least amount of variables. Meaning it's the "simplest" model and should generalize better.